# Appending headers to Rspec controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write out tests for a controller of mine that takes in requests from external services. So far this is my test:

```
describe ApplyController do
  context 'when valid' do
    let(:parameters) do
      file = File.join File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'samples', 'Indeed.json'
      JSON.parse(File.read file)
    end
    let(:signature) { 'GC02UVj0d4bqa5peNFHdPQAZ2BI=' }

    subject(:response) { post :indeed, parameters, 'X-Indeed-Signature' => signature }

    it 'returns 200 ok if Request is valid' do
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
  end
end
```

This should work according to the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/controller-specs/cookies) I could [find](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#setting-headers-and-cgi-variables).

My controller right now looks something like this:

```
class ApplyController < Application Controller
  def indeed
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

When I get into Pry in my test and try to check the value of `request.headers['X-Indeed-Signature']` I always just get `nil`

Is there something that I am missing? I am using Rails 3.2 and Rspec 3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using `@request.env` instead of `@request.headers` like so:

```
describe ApplyController do
  context 'when valid' do
    let(:parameters) do
      file = File.join File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'samples', 'Indeed.json'
      JSON.parse(File.read file)
    end
    let(:signature) { 'GC02UVj0d4bqa5peNFHdPQAZ2BI=' }

    it 'returns 200 ok if Request is valid' do
      @request.env['X-Indeed-Signature'] = signature
      post :indeed, parameters
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In Rails 5, you can do ```request.env['X-Indeed-Signature'] = signature```

Answer (score 23):

I think you want (straight from one of your links)

```
it "returns 200 ok"
  @request.headers['X-Indeed-Signature'] = signature
  post :indeed, parameters
  response.status.should == 200
end
```

You don't need subject(:response)

Comment: It turns out I actually needed to use `@request.env['X-Indeed-Signature']` instead of `@request.headers`

Comment: It looks to me like you need `@request.env` in Rails 3 and `@request.headers` in Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

I had many issues with the rubocop to avoid it, I wanted to put the headers into let. In addition call request.headers.merge! instead of @request.headers['key']=value.

I took the fix from [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1655):

```
describe ApplyController do
  context 'when valid' do
    let(:parameters) do
      file = File.join File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'samples', 'Indeed.json'
      JSON.parse(File.read file)
    end
    let(:headers) do
      {
        signature: 'GC02UVj0d4bqa5peNFHdPQAZ2BI='
      } 


    it 'returns 200 ok if Request is valid' do
      request.headers.merge! headers
      post :indeed, parameters
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is pretty silly of rspec.

**Custom headers in Request Specs**

```
headers = {
  'AUTH' => 'super secret key'
}

post '/api/some_action', { user_id: 1337 }.to_json, headers
```

And in your controller:

```
def some_action
  token = request.headers['AUTH']
end
```

**Custom headers in Controller Specs**

```
headers = {
  'AUTH' => 'super secret key'
}

post '/api/some_action', { user_id: 1337 }, headers
```

And in your controller:

```
def some_action
  token = request.headers['rack.session']['AUTH']
end
```

Just sharing the differences I had between the two. I don't believe I have any special configuration in rspec or rails to have the two different spec types' headers to be placed differently.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this will only work for spec type `:request` but not for spec type `:controller`