# How would I turn this curl request into an RSpec test for this controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, rspec

I used curl to test a to see if this controller would receive incoming requests but now I want to make a RSPEC test how would I turn this curl line: `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Origin: requesting.url.site" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"foobar"}'  http://arbitrary.site` into a RSPEC Post test for create?

```
class API::EventsController < ApplicationController

 skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #for this example skip the authenticity_token
 before_action :set_access_control_headers

def preflight
 head 200
end

def set_access_control_headers
 headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
 headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
 headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
end
def create
 registered_application = RegisteredApplication.find_by(url: request.env['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
  if registered_application == nil
    render json: {errors: "Unregistered application"}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  else
    @event = registered_application.events.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
      render json: @event, status: :created
    else
      render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end

 private
  def event_params
   params.require(:event).permit(:name)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just append headers to the usual rspec controller post action.

It is already answered here [Appending headers to Rspec controller tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529917/appending-headers-to-rspec-controller-tests)